# Media module function overriting, user can see only own media

Tags: 7, hooks, media

As title says, I need to override few media module functions and add some extra conditions when selecting media. I wanted to create new module that extends media module and overrides those functions but without success.

I wanted to override function

```
function media_admin_list(&$parent_form)
```

and to add this line so media module will select media from logged in user

```
$query = db_select('file_managed', 'f')->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');
$query->join('users', 'u', 'f.uid = u.uid');
$query->fields('f', array('fid'));
$query->fields('u', array('uid'));
$query->condition('f.status', FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT);
$query->condition('u.uid', $user_id, "=");
$query->limit($limit);
$query->orderByHeader($header);
```

As you can see in code above, we have condition for selecting media from specific user.

Please advise how to override this function in my own module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion I can come up with is to use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter the value of `$form['admin']['#files']` (inspect the form array on the `/admin/content/media` page) by calling your own version of `media_admin_list()` with an altered query.

Something like:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'media_admin') {
        $form['admin']['#files'] = custom_media_admin_list();
    }
}
```

This is slightly inefficient as the original function has already run but I can't see a way to alter it before the initial form array has been built.

Comment: Thanks @Felix for your answer but this didn't solve my problem. Code goes through my custom function, but after that code goes through original function and I have same result again.

Comment: Arr - in that case make your changes in an #after_build callback.